# Unity error when execute game in local WebGL export

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm develop my first game in Unity but when I try to run the game with the build WebGL option show many error.

How can solve this?

```
    An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
abort(153) at jsStackTrace@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:16316
stackTrace@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:16487
abort@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:748
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[36750]:0xa07802
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[17541]:0x6a9462
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[36221]:0x9f1a90
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[24936]:0x7d9bed
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[36560]:0xa06d5f
unityFramework/Module.dynCall_iiiii@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:423039
invoke_iiiii@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:309514
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[34598]:0x9adf58
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[34049]:0x99681e
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[4209]:0x181d2c
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[4207]:0x1819fc
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10241]:0x3a5fd1
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10217]:0x3a49d5
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[12469]:0x4d6da2
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[12468]:0x4d6abc
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10661]:0x3d46a5
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10338]:0x3aefec
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10338]:0x3af001
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10333]:0x3aeb9b
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[10326]:0x3acfb4
@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.wasm.gz:wasm-function[36574]:0xa06f8e
unityFramework/Module.dynCall_v@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:430088
browserIterationFunc@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:152296
runIter@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:155369
Browser_mainLoop_runner@http://localhost:41897/Build/platform.framework.js.gz:2:153831
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the developer Console to see the exact errors / network activity.

- Are you sure your backend supports serving of pre-compressed files? (gzip)
- Is the content encoding correct for your files?

Max